# Is it safe to store the pointer to the data of a std::string?

Tags: c++

My question revolves around the mechanics of copy-construction and reallocation.

I have a class, that collects strings. After adding a string to the collection, the string is copied and stored in a vector. But as I also need access to the collection of all the string as `const char * const*`, I also store the pointers to the data of each string via `.c_str()`.

```
class MyStrings {
private:
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::vector<const char*> cStringPointers;
public:
    const char *const *Data() const
    {
        return this->cStringPointers.data();
    }

    void Add(const std::string &name)
    {
        // copy [name] and store the copy in [this->names].
        this->names.push_back(name); 
        // Store the pointer to the data of the copy.
        this->cStringPointers.push_back(this->names.back().c_str());
    }
}
```

I am aware, that storing pointers to elements of a vector is bad, because when the vector gets resized, i.e. has to reallocate his memory, those pointers would not be valid anymore.

But I am storing just the pointers to the data. So here is what I think:

If `names` gets resized, it will move-construct all the strings it contains and so those strings will not allocate new memory, but instead just use the already allocated memory and so my pointers in `cStringPointers` would still be valid.

My question is now simply: Have I missed something that would make this code unsafe or cause undefined behaviour?

(Assuming that I don't use any exotical architexture and or compiler.)

Comment: why store them apart from the string? Instead you can call `c_str` whenever you need it

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I believe what OP needs is an array of pointers for some reason (e.g., to be passed to some C function).

Comment: Do you know the number of records (names) in advance? If yes, you can reserve space for `names` and then, no reallocation should happen. Another option would be to check for reallocation (compare size and capacity of `names`) and if it happens, reconstruct the whole array `cStringPointers`.

Comment: Yes, @DanielLangr is right, I need that for some C-Interface, to be more specific for Vulkan, because it requires the extension and layer names as a const char * const*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My question is now simply: Have I missed something that would make
>   this code unsafe or cause undefined behaviour?

Yes: you have missed Small String Optimization. It is permitted by the standard and widely implemented, and will lead to dangling pointers as the strings *actually* move their data to their new location.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this :)

Answer (score 4):

This is not safe. Even the `cStringPointers` is not safe.

Note standard library for most compilers implement something called: Small String Optimization (SSO). Basically in SSO if string is small (in gcc 15 characters), memory for that string is not allocated in heap, but it is kept directly inside `std::basic_string` class. To achieve that `std::basic_string` is larger then size required for pointers (begin, end, capacity).

This means that if vector is relocated, small string will change their position.
Longer string will remain valid since they are allocated on heap an this will not be copied.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is now simply: Have I missed something that would make this code unsafe or cause undefined behaviour?

Yes. This particular assumption is up to the implementation and thus UB even if any common implementations of `std::string` *would* move the data of the string and keep pointers valid. Only when such a detail is actually guaranteed by the standard can you rely on it. (Commonly found in sections entitled "Iterator validity" and such.) In the [documentation of `std::string`'s move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) (No. 2) it explicitly states:

> Unlike other container move assignments, references, pointers, and iterators to str may be invalidated.

Here, this assumption actually happens to be wrong for most implementations as those use a small string optimization. That will store strings up to a certain size ("small strings") in the `string` object itself rather than allocating memory dynamically. Thus, when the `string` is moved, it can only avoid copying long strings which are dynamically allocated while small strings are actually copied. Thus `c_str()` will yield a different pointer after a move of small strings.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a relevant quote from the C++ Standard [[string.require.4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.require#4):

> References, **pointers**, and iterators referring to the elements of a `basic_­string` sequence **may be invalidated** by the following uses of that `basic_­string` object:
>
> — **Passing as an argument to any standard library function taking a reference to non-const `basic_­string` as an argument.**

Move construction of strings during vector reallocation is exactly such a case, since the move constructor takes a reference to a non-const string as an argument.